# How to share local video file's stream using Webrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-streaming, peer-connection

i tried to share local video file's stream in webrtc. it was successful in tomcat localhost but fails on running in website.
just when i share navigator.mediaDevices's stream it works every where but sharing video file's stream works only in localhost.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var stream;
var rTCPeerConnection;

 /*
  stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: true
            });
 */
  
 video.onloadeddata = function(){
    if ($.browser.mozilla){
            stream = this.mozCaptureStream();
                }else{  
            stream = this.captureStream();
                }
    }
    
     video.src= "./myfile.webm";

function share_stream_to_peerConnection(){
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track =>  rTCPeerConnection.addTrack(track, stream)  );
}
```

Comment: `but fails` in what way? are there errors in your browser? errors on the server?

Comment: @jaromanda-x  i checked video file's stream. no problem. but after sharing just i get this error message: "webrtc failed!"

Comment: that's not a very helpful error, is it. A good system would tell you why - but you haven't even said where you see this error message

Comment: i checked video file's stream in some browsers and there were no problem, also i checked server error logs and got no problem, but after sharing video tracks i will get in browser console this error: "WebRTC: ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details"

Comment: and have you done any of those things?

Comment: @jaromanda-x yes. i tested navigator.mediaDevices's stream. it's ok. but by video file's stream sharing makes webrtc connection failed. should video tag has some special attributes? or should video file be a in a special format? like mp4 or ts

Comment: is webrtc limited to https?

Comment: no. there is no limitation

Comment: Hi, does the pc you are hosting your app with have acces to internet?

Comment: @Giverseal  yes. it has full access to internet

Answer (score 0):

this  is  a simple example i  made  to share file through webRTC, here you can  see how webRTC data flow works. I  used a websocket  to handle the message between  2 users. Maybe can be helpfull.

[https://bit.cloud/intershare/galacfetch/hooks/web-rtc-local-share/~code/src/web-rtc-local-share.ts](https://bit.cloud/intershare/galacfetch/hooks/web-rtc-local-share/%7Ecode/src/web-rtc-local-share.ts)

```
// and here  an example of the  websocket in the backend side.
  let connectedClients = [];

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // connected user
    connectedClients.push(socket.id);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      const index = connectedClients.indexOf(socket.id);
      if (index > -1) {
        connectedClients.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });

    // Manejar oferta SDP
    socket.on('offer', (offer) => {
      const randomClients = getRandomClients(10, socket.id, connectedClients);
      if (randomClients.includes(socket.id)) {
        randomClients.forEach((clientId) => {
          socket.to(clientId).emit('offer', offer, socket.id);
        });
      }
    });

    // Manejar respuesta SDP
    socket.on('answer', (answer) => {
      const randomClients = getRandomClients(10, socket.id);
      if (randomClients.includes(socket.id)) {
        randomClients.forEach((clientId) => {
          socket.to(clientId).emit('answer', answer);
        });
      }
    });

    // Manejar ICE candidates
    socket.on('ice-candidate', (iceCandidate) => {
      const randomClients = getRandomClients(10, socket.id);
      if (randomClients.includes(socket.id)) {
        randomClients.forEach((clientId) => {
          socket.to(clientId).emit('ice-candidate', iceCandidate);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```